# Proper standby status update in streaming replication protocol

Tags: postgresql, logical-replication, logical-decoding

Question is about [streaming replication protocol](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/protocol-replication.html).
Which is extremely simple, and was made for physical replication and is capable of:

- Sending server status > `Primary keepalive message`
- Receiving replica status > `Standby status update`
- Send WAL data > `XLogData`

There is also logical decoding, uses same XLogData frames to send data decoded from WAL by plugin, like `pglogical` instead of raw WAL.

Streaming Replication expects me to commit Standby status update, in order to free resources and remove old WAL, which according to docs

> The location of the last WAL byte + 1 ...

`pglogical` returns its own LSN positions using its own messages within XLogData frames, but those are not usable.

Logical decoding does not work, when data is written to a different DB. And slot position yet needs to be updated, otherwise slot would be lost.
So, the only way is to send LSN positions from `Primary keepalive message`, which according to docs sends

> The current end of WAL on the server.

Which is confusing. What if slot is on position 100 and the server is already on 200?

### So,

after experimenting and checking sources of pg_recvlogical, understood, that `Primary keepalive message` does not mean "The current end of WAL on the server", but in reality gradually increases from slot position up to the current (`pg_current_wal_lsn()`) server LSN. Having XLogData frames in between (if any).
Seems, like messages are received sequentially ordered by LSN.

And now, questions:

Q1) Is it documented somewhere?

Q2) Does it make sense? Did I misunderstand anything?

Q3) Are streaming messages always sorted by LSN?

Q4) Is it okay to commit positions from `Primary keepalive message`?

Comment: Docs says:  "The location of the last WAL byte + 1 ...", which is rather confusing. Also, haven't found this in `pg_recvlogical` sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/8ac700acffc7b17d88414be47b8dff44fb1ea681/src/backend/replication/walsender.c#L3607-L3609)

> writePtr is the location up to which the WAL is sent. It is essentially
> the same as sentPtr but in some cases, we need to send keep alive before
> sentPtr is updated like when skipping empty transactions.

Which is then written in

```cpp
pq_sendint64(&output_message, XLogRecPtrIsInvalid(writePtr) ? sentPtr : writePtr);
```

This means, that **The current end of WAL on the server.** is actually **the location up to which the WAL is sent**

Also [here](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/f234b8cd16a4ba6e12cc51a36c8e499661d535bb/src/backend/replication/walreceiver.c#L1256) in `walreceiver.c` it says:

> 'walEnd' and 'sendTime' are the end-of-WAL and timestamp of the latest message, reported by primary.

Comment: I'm not sure this is true. It appears that `walEnd` and `dataStart` are always _the same_ for logical replication. See https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_15_4/src/backend/replication/walsender.c#L1366

Comment: @BenLongo, can you give me an additional hint, on what to double-check and how to update the answer?

Comment: See the discussion here: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/5251#issuecomment-1707033864